# How to remove left recursion from a grammar with beta missing?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, left-recursion

Here's the problem:

A -> A*B | A+CDE | Aab

All of the productions start with A. I guess that satisfies the rule? As you can see, it is missing beta. How do I perform left recursion on it? Can left recursion be even performed on it?

What I have learned so far is that if it was like this: A -> A*B | A+CDE | Aab | b

Then I would consider b as beta and solve as:

A  -> bA'

A' -> *BA' | +CDEA' | abA' | ϵ

Without beta, I am confused. What do I consider as beta?

Comment: The one whose right-recursion you are trying to eliminate (A). "All the productions start with A" --> there is no way to terminate the recursion. It's like writing a recursive function without a base condition. The only place it can go is stack overflow and I'm not talking about this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think firstly it is needed to add new rule to A production to stop recursion.
Something like **b** in your example.

```
A -> A*B | A+CDE | Aab | b
```

If this is not possible I guess production will looks like this:

```
A -> A*B | A+CDE | Aab | e
```

So, first step will be left factoring:

```
A -> AT | e
T -> *B | +CDE | ab
```

And then remove left recursion:

```
A -> A'
A' -> TA' | e
T -> *B | +CDE | ab
```

Comment: @SakibArifin yes, but e is used only for stopping infinite recursion, it means empty string. You can use without it and there will be no left recursion as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce the grammar by removing all useless and non-productive non-terminals before you try to remove right-recursion. Since `A` is non-productive (it has no non-recursive production), it will get eliminated along with any production which uses it. That certainly gets rid of the left-recursion :-).